# Run command for Adobe Flash settings

Tags: windows, command-line, flash, control-panel, run-dialog

Is there a run command that brings up the Adobe Flash settings in the Control Panel?

Run commands such as WinKey+R and typing cmd, msconfig, control, etc. but to bring up the flash player settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running `FlashPlayerCPLApp.cpl`